# C++ / Qt Class Initialization

Tags: c++, qt

I'm new to C++ and I'm trying to find the proper way to initialize this class.

Here is the code:

```
void NewDialog::createNew()
{
    InkSpot *ink;
    ink = new InkSpot(this);
    InkPuppet *puppet;
    puppet->ui->canvas->addWidget(ink->widget);
    close();
}
```

Now, for `InkSpot *ink;` & `ink = new InkSpot(this);` it works fine because I actually DO need a new InkSpot created.

But I do not need a new `InkPuppet *puppet` created, I simply need to refer to it's UI. Using the above code `puppet->ui->canvas->addWidget(ink->widget);` causes the program to crash because it is not being initialized.

The whole issue here is, that to initialize a new class I know how to do it, but initializing a pre-existing class I'm not sure how to refer to it.

**newdialog.h**

```
#ifndef NEWDIALOG_H
#define NEWDIALOG_H

#include "inkspot.h"
#include "inkpuppet.h"
#include "ui_inkpuppet.h"

#include <QDialog>

namespace Ui {
class NewDialog;
}

class NewDialog : public QDialog
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit NewDialog(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~NewDialog();
    InkPuppet *pointerToPuppet;

private:
    Ui::NewDialog *ui;

private slots:
    void createNew(InkPuppet *existingPuppet);

};

#endif // NEWDIALOG_H
```

**inkpuppet.h**

```
#ifndef INKPUPPET_H
#define INKPUPPET_H

#include "inkspot.h"
#include "ui_inkpuppet.h"

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QWidget>

namespace Ui {
class InkPuppet;
}

class InkPuppet : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit InkPuppet(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~InkPuppet();

    Ui::InkPuppet *ui;

private slots:
    void setMinimum(int value);
    void setMaximum(int value);
    void actionNew();
    void actionAbout();
    void testButton();
};

#endif // INKPUPPET_H
```

Comment: You are not initializing `puppet`, so the pointer is pointing somewhere, which causes access violations.

Comment: Did you try passing the pointer to the already existing `InkPuppet` as an argument, something like: `createNew(Inkpuppet *existingPuppet)`?

Comment: I pretty much already said that, but that wasn't the question, the question was HOW do I initialize it without creating another instance? The problem is that I need to set a QWidget parent in the main window from an external class, but I can't figure out how to initialize that class. Creating a new class wont work.

Comment: OK maybe @Joum is right: you might pass the widget you'd like to add as an argument of your method.

Comment: @Joum ; `void createNew(InkPuppet *puppet);` in the header is returning `x:\development\inkpuppet\newdialog.h:26: error: C2061: syntax error : identifier 'InkPuppet'` - Assume I'm doing something wrong here.

Comment: I have edited the main post with newdialog.h

Comment: It would be interesting to know where the existing InkPuppet is actually declared and initialized.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, what I meant with my above comment was, in the section/function where you call `createNew(InkPuppet *existingPuppet)` you should have something like:

```
// initialize the InkPuppet object
InkPuppet * existingPuppet = new InkPuppet();
// then call the function you have to create a new InkBlob for that InkPuppet

// (...) you probably have here some code to create/execute the dialog

dialog.createNew(existingPuppet);
```

All this assuming that the `dialog` you created is of the `NewDialog` class you have above.
What you get with this is that your `InkPuppet` is initialized *before* and *independently* of the object you want to use it for. Think of it like using a *knife* to cut a *steak* before the *steak* exists - it wouldn't be possible.

Also, whenever you do this, you should check before passing the pointer as an argument, if the pointer actually *exists*. Usually something like:

```
if(pointer!=0)
{
    // pointer exists, do something
    functionThatUsesThePointerAsArg(pointer);
}
```

**UPDATE:**

I noticed in your code that you also created an `InkSpot` instance in your function. Note that this won't be available to your `InkPuppet` class unless you make it so in the `NewDialog` class. If you don't do this, and sticking to the previous metaphor, it's like the `NewDialog` class has a *knife*, and doesn't share it with anyone who might need, like `InkPuppet`, for instance.

In `newdialog.h` try something like:

```
class NewDialog : public QDialog
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit NewDialog(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~NewDialog();

    // add this:
    InkPuppet* pointerToPuppet;

private:
    Ui::NewDialog *ui;

private slots:
    void createNew(InkPuppet *existingPuppet);

};
```

And then, in the function description:

```
void NewDialog::createNew(InkPuppet * existingPuppet){
    // (...)
    this->pointerToPuppet = existingPuppet;
    // (...)
}
```

**UPDATE2:**

So the first problem I found is that your `InkPuppet` is a `QMainWindow`, so if you try to create a new instance of it *inside of itself*, that might explain why it blows up. :) So instead of what I suggested earlier, use maybe `this` instead of creating a new instance:

```
dialog.createNew(this);
```

As for the errors in the compiler, I can't actually figure them out, sorry. :( But I suspect it might relate to the fact that you might have deleted something you shouldn't... like the `inkpuppet.h`, maybe? that would explain why the compiler doesn't recognize the `InkPuppet * existingPuppet;` pointer as a *type* and tries to assume `int`.

Comment: That causes a crash on startup :( My QPaintDevice requires that a QApplication be present, and doing this messes up the order or something along those lines. Should I just post all my code? I was trying to avoid it so that people wouldn't have to truck through it.

Comment: I don't mean to put you down from your efforts, but please understand that it's hard to share any insights without knowing the whole problem. What I suggested here shouldn't interfere with  `QPaintDevice` or `QApplication`, I think, but of course, it depends on _how_ your code is actually written. I would suggest trying to break your problem down into smaller pieces and handle them one at a time. Also, keep updating the question with compile errors/debug messages as it might help find the problem. You **should** post your code, but only the relevant sections.

Comment: I read your edit; I think it'd work except I've encountered a bug. In ALL of my header files I can no longer point to anything (edit : correction I can no longer point to class files). It returns `x:\development\inkpuppet\newdialog.h:21: error: C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '*'` and `x:\development\inkpuppet\newdialog.h:21: error: C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int` Everything was working then it just stopped and started complaining about pre-existing code. I have deleted build folder, restarted QT Creator etc, but no dice.

Comment: Paste your `inkpuppet.h` and your `newdialog.h`, please.

Comment: In your edit I'm actually not sure what you're saying to do. Are you saying `void NewDialog::createNew(this)` ? Maybe I'm just tired and missing something obvious. `void createNew(this);` is what I have in the header and it's saying: `x:\development\inkpuppet\newdialog.h:27: error: C2059: syntax error : 'this'` - Maybe this is also related to my bug. I don't know how I'm meant to continue with such a serious bug and I have no idea how to fix it. Google is not being helpful.

Comment: No. That is the _descriptor_ in the header. That should remain as `void createNew(InkPuppet *existingPuppet);`. Use `dialog.createNew(this);` when (and after) you create the instance of `dialog`, ie, somewhere in `inkpuppet.cpp`.

Comment: There are a few key aspects of the general OOP design/code workflow that seem to be very new to you with C++/Qt. Instead of jumping into design, I would advise you to start by looking at code and examples that cover many of the basics: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/demos.html

Comment: `nDialog->createNew(this);` is returning `X:\Development\InkPuppet\inkpuppet.cpp:51: error: C2660: 'NewDialog::createNew' : function does not take 1 arguments` .. pretty sure it does?

Comment: After the bugs were fixed your answer worked - Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you may do that as follows since your purpose is to add `ink` into `puppet`. Is it? Hope it works for you:

```
void NewDialog::createNew()
{
    InkSpot *ink = new InkSpot();
    InkPuppet *puppet = new InkPuppet(this);
    puppet->ui->canvas->addWidget(ink->widget);
    close();
}
```

In your question you are not initializing `puppet`, which causes access violation when calling methods from the object.

Comment: As stated, I've tried doing it that way and it wont work because it's creating a NEW InkPuppet instance, so it will set the canvas' widget (ink->widget) into the old one which will no longer be present. At least I think that's what's happening, point is if I do it that way then it doesn't work, and if I make a button inside the main class (InkPuppet) that does the EXACT same thing but without having to initialize puppet, it then works.